# Dynamic protocol conformance in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Hi I am struggle to solve the problem dynamic protocol conformance in swift language. Please see code.

**Protocol:**

```
protocol Object {

    init(by object: [String: Any])
}
```

Custom structs with protocol object conformance:

```
struct Tree: Object {

    let treeName: String

    init(by object: [String: Any]) {

        self.treeName = object["tree"] as? String ?? "Notree"
    }
}

struct Plant: Object {

    let plantName: String

    init(by object: [String : Any]) {

        self.plantName = object["tree"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

The above code just fine until the object is `[String: Any]`. I can't use [[String: Any]] like below.

```
let coconut = ["tree":"Coconut"] // => This fine
let allTrees = [["tree":"Apple"],["tree":"Orange"],["tree":"Jakfruit"]] //=> Here is the problem

 let aTree = Tree(by: coconut)
 let bTree = Tree(by: ["data":allTrees])
 let cTree = Plant(by: ["data":allTrees])
```

I can't use array of objects. So, I used to store objects in to key "data". Now I used `extension: Array` confirm protocol object.

```
extension Array: Object where Element == Object{

    init(by object: [String : Any]) {

        if let data = object["data"] as? [[String: Any]]{

            self  = data.map({ (object) -> Object in

//                return Plant.init(by: object) // => Works, But I need dynamic confirmance
//                return Tree.init(by: object) // => Works, But I need dynamic confirmance

                return Object.init(by: object) //=> How can I do?
            })
        }else{

            self = []
        }
    }
}
```

The return `Object` shows error ***Protocol type 'Object' cannot be instantiated***. I tried lot to solve but not able.

Can someone suggest better idea or solution for this problem? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not use the constraint `== Object`. You want to say that not only `[Object]` is an `Object`, but also `[Plant]` and `[Tree]` are `Object`s too, right? For that, you should use the `: Object` constraint. Second, you can use `Element.init` to initialise a new `Element` of the array. Because of the constraint `Element : Object`, we know that a `init(by:)` initialiser exists:

```
extension Array: Object where Element: Object{

    init(by object: [String : Any]) {

        if let data = object["data"] as? [[String: Any]]{

            self  = data.map({ (object) in

                return Element.init(by: object)
            })
        }else{

            self = []
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let trees = [Tree](by: ["data": allTrees])
```

Here's what I think a more Swifty version of your code, making use of [*failable initialisers*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224) - initialisers that return `nil` when they fail to initialise the object:

```
protocol Object {

    init?(by object: [String: Any])
}


struct Tree: Object {

    let treeName: String

    init?(by object: [String: Any]) {

        if let treeName = object["tree"] as? String {
            self.treeName = treeName
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Plant: Object {

    let plantName: String

    init?(by object: [String : Any]) {

        if let plantName = object["tree"] as? String {
            self.plantName = plantName
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Array: Object where Element: Object{

    init?(by object: [String : Any]) {

        if let data = object["data"] as? [[String: Any]]{
            self  = data.compactMap(Element.init)
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent about few hours to find this.